# Visual studio 22 doesn't attach to started process

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-standard, .net-7.0

I have small sproblem with my project, I have application.Core which is ClassLibrary project .net standard 2.0 where i add reference to asembly "Company.ExternalApp.dll" which is created using .net framework 4.5, it start Ok but breakpoint are not hited, i realized when i run app fron debug folder and use Debug -> Attach to process and selected it, then debuging works perfect.
Any idea how to debug it on visual studio Start button?
PS. i created Launch profile "Executable" where i selected exe file in debug output dir. with selected "Enable native code debugging"

btw. sorry for my english :D

I try creating new launch profile, restart visual studio, restart computer.

I want to debug my project without manualu executing application.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on application.Core code where that assembly should have been loaded.  When it breaks, use Debug > Windows > Modules, locate Company.ExternalApp.dll in the list.   You can see if the debugger could find the .pdb file and doesn't treat it as external code.

Comment: @HansPassant My classes only inherits from Company.ExternalApp.dll, and i dont load it via code. Also i try to check in Modules but list is empty, i also do this when run then attach to process, and list have multiple row

Comment: That list must not be empty.  Only look at it when the debugger landed on a breakpoint.

Comment: I check this pdb and it's User Code: yes, Symbol Status: Symbol loaded.

Comment: I propably have solution for that, mabe it's not perfect but it work ;) I create .net framework 4.8.1 ClassLibrary, and in Properties-> Debug -> Start external program, i select exe from other project debug folder.